# Is it possible to disable alternating rows for a single column in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to add a column to an already populated DataGridView but I need this column cells to be all the same color since it is the sum of all the columns on each row.

I add the column this way:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Acumulable", typeof(float));
dt.Columns["Acumulable"].Expression = "Enero+Febrero+Marzo+Abril+Mayo+Junio+Julio+Agosto+Septiembre+Octubre+Noviembre+Diciembre";
```

And I set the color like this:

```
DGVGastosVariables.Columns["Acumulable"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#3498DB");
```

It works fine since it does change the color of the cells but it keeps the alternating row pattern.

Is there a way to disable the alternating rows for that column in particular?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Subscribe your `DataGridView` to `CellFormatting` event:

```
private void DataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == /* Acumulable column index */)
    {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#3498DB");
    }
}
```

Also you can use `CellPainting` event.